# Find all data related to a specific user in AWS (Architecture)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a scenario where I want to use different storage services of AWS like **S3** and **DynamoDB**. One user can have information attached to him and saved in different services. Now I want to implement a RESTful API that allows the user to retrieve all of his data.

How can I make sure that I find all data. Is there any architecture or specific service that allows me to find all data attached to a user (user is identified by his ID)?

Comment: Hi, there. Unfortunately that is such a broad question, that no one is able to give you a concrete answer. There are tons of ways to achieve this. You need to be much more specific.

Comment: What about check [AWS EMR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-what-is-emr.html) ?